# Can no longer access the Settings panel

Tags: 18.04, system-settings

when I click on the "Settings Icon" (the one next to the Power Off icon), nothing happens.  In `/var/log/syslog`, I found the following message:

```
Sep 26 10:33:06 Narnar gnome-shell[1485]: JS ERROR: TypeError: app is null#012_onSettingsClicked@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/system.js:335:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_createSubMenu/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/system.js:265:57
```

In addition, "Settings" is no longer showing up as a searched result when I attempt to find it via the "activities search bar" (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug in `gnome-shell`

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/140

The bug was fixed 3 weeks ago and should make it's way to your install. In the meantime there are some workarounds suggested, the easiest being:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-shell
gnome-session-quit --power-off
```

Now when you start the computer again the issue should be gone, but may appear again until that newer version of the package reaches your installation.

Comment: Have the same problem when installing a new version of `nodejs` using `nvm`. 
When i switch back to my older nodejs version it started to work.

Answer (score 3):

I had same symptoms. Nothing happened on the Settings icon. Looking at output from `journalctl -r`, I saw the same error as you. It turned out the gnome-control-center was no longer installed. For all I know, it could have been missing since a year ago, when you also had this problem.

But it was easy to fix. Just install it again:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```